# JMeter Performance bench mark criteria

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

Could any team assist me for sharing standard all J-Meter performance mark criteria while performing J-Meter Performance testing for min 1000 user .it means that how we can decide what parameter(or threshold) caused for deciding load /performance testing with route cause and proposed solution after generating html report with non-GUI with completed scenario.

Thanks 
Amit G

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard", the acceptance criteria normally are being dictated by the business requirements which might differ depending on the nature of the application

- for real-time trading a couple of milliseconds delay is critical, companies invest into locating their highly performing servers physically close to exchange servers because even light speed matters for their scenarios
- for normal applications used by people (i.e. news portals, e-commerce websites, etc.) the accepted load time would be 2-3 seconds, if [people have to wait more - most probably they will switch somewhere else and never return](https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/your-website-design-should-load-in-4-seconds/). Moreover, search engines tend to rank slow websites lower
- for internal applications which are being used inside the company response time doesn't really matter cause people will have to use particular this application, but you still might report large response times like: "if a person who earns $18 per hour has to wait for 10 seconds for each operation and the number of operations per day is 100 and number of personnel is 3000 the organization looses $15 000 every single day or $5 475 000 a year"

---

So I would recommend taking the following steps:

1. Check for existing [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)s or [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)s, it might be the case the document, you got these 1000 users contains some information regarding maximum response time or minimum throughput (requests per unit of time)
2. If there are no formal acceptance criteria defined you could go for [other performance testing types](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough/):

   - [Soak testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) - putting your application under the prolonged load to see whether it performs consistently and there are no obvious [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
   - [Stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) - starting with low number of users and gradually increasing the load until errors start occurring. This way you will be able to report correlation between increasing number of users and increasing response time/number of errors, identify [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) (the maximum number of users which application can efficiently support), [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) (breaking point), etc.